# UI-Router 1.0.0-beta.3 ui-sref params child routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Attempting to navigate to a child route of a parent route with a parameter. The ng-click does go off and I can see it in the console registering the click, but I get no changes to the state.  Am I declaring the ui-sref wrong?

```
<body ng-controller="myController as $ctrl" style="{margin-top: 70px;}">
<div>
  <button><a ui-sref="idLevel.index({something: 1})" ng-click="$ctrl.test()">Link1</a></button>
  <button><a ui-sref="idLevel.other({something: 2})" ng-click="$ctrl.test2()">link2</a></button>
</div>
<ui-view>
  <div>
    test
  </div>
</ui-view>
```

```
// Code goes here

function appRoute($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
  $stateProvider
    .state('idLevel', {
      url: '/:something',
      abstract: true,
    })
    .state('idLevel.index', {
      url: '/index/',
      component: 'component1'
    })
    .state('idLevel.other', {
      url: '/other/',
      component: 'component2'
    })
}

var component1 = {
  template: '<h1>indexRoute</h1><br><p>HELP!!{{$ctrl.params}}</p>',
  controller: function($stateParams) {
    var ctrl = this;
    console.log('component1', $stateParams);
    ctrl.params = $stateParams.id;
  }
};

var component2 = {
  template: '<div><h1>otherRoute</h1><br><p>Help2 {{$ctrl.params}}</div>',
  controller: function($stateParams) {
    var ctrl = this;
    console.log('component2', $stateParams);
    ctrl.params = $stateParams.id;
  }
};

function myController($stateParams) {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.test = test;
  ctrl.test2 = test2;

  function test() {
    console.log('TEST LINK!', $stateParams.id)
  }

  function test2() {
    console.log('TEST 2', $stateParams.id)
  }
}

angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router'])
  .config(appRoute)
  .controller('myController', myController)
  .component('component1', component1)
  .component('component2', component2);
myController.$inject = ['$stateParams'];
appRoute.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider'];
component1.$inject = ['$stateParams'];
component2.$inject = ['$stateParams'];
```

Plnkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rz3AbgnYnWI34DjuByY6?p=preview)

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but I can't figure out why its not allowing me to hit the route.

Comment: [Newer Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rz3AbgnYnWI34DjuByY6?p=preview) I think I've got the right plnkr this time.

Comment: Well dangit, it seems to be working now. I think I'll just give up tonight.

Answer (score 0):

A parent state needs to have a `<ui-view>` in it's template for child states to render in.

Note that in plunker you can't use `/` as base since the editor is not in the root of site

[Updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zIJQ8vk61JIUA7xQaRz4?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry plnkr wasn't showing the most updated one I was working on.  
I tried adding a <div ui-view></div> to the parent state but I still wasn't getting it.

Comment: Please debug your demos. Both had syntax problems

Answer (score 0):

firstly your plunkr looks a bit different to the code you've shown, secondly, from what I can see, the plunkr seems to be working - you are getting a state change - you cant see it because the content is hidden behind the title nav bar.

If you open the plunkr in the separate window (blue button) you can just see the content under the navbar changing as you click the links.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason plnkr wasn't putting up the version I had actually gotten it to duplicate my problem in.